# Groupby dataframe on some columns and list other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a inital dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'job': ['job1', None, None, 'job3', None, None, 'job4', None, None, None, 'job5', None, None, None, 'job6', None, None, None, None],
    'name': ['n_j1', None, None, 'n_j3', None, None, 'n_j4', None, None, None, 'nj5', None, None, None, 'nj6', None, None, None, None],
    'schedule': ['01', None, None, '06', None, None, '09', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    'task_type': ['START', 'TA', 'END', 'START', 'TB', 'END', 'START', 'TB', 'TB', 'END', 'START', 'TA', 'TA', 'END', 'START', 'TA', 'TA', 'TA', 'END'],
    'task': [None, 'task12', None, None, 'task31', None, None, 'task18', 'nt6', None, None, 'task3', 'task7', None, None, 'task19', 'task6', 'task88', None],
    'task_name': [None, 'name_t12', None, None, 'name_t31', None, None, 'name_t18', 'n_t5', None, None, 'name_t33', 'n7', None, None, 'name_t19', 'n6', 'n88', None]
})
```

```
     job  name schedule task_type    task task_name
0   job1  n_j1       01     START    None      None
1   None  None     None        TA  task12  name_t12
2   None  None     None       END    None      None
3   job3  n_j3       06     START    None      None
4   None  None     None        TB  task31  name_t31
5   None  None     None       END    None      None
6   job4  n_j4       09     START    None      None
7   None  None     None        TB  task18  name_t18
8   None  None     None        TB     nt6      n_t5
9   None  None     None       END    None      None
10  job5   nj5     None     START    None      None
11  None  None     None        TA   task3  name_t33
12  None  None     None        TA   task7        n7
13  None  None     None       END    None      None
14  job6   nj6     None     START    None      None
15  None  None     None        TA  task19  name_t19
16  None  None     None        TA   task6        n6
17  None  None     None        TA  task88       n88
18  None  None     None       END    None      None
```

My expected result is:

```
    job  name schedule          types                   tasks              n_names
0  job1  n_j1       01          [TA]                 [task12]           [name_t12]
1  job3  n_j3       06          [TB]                 [task31]           [name_t31]
2  job4  n_j4       09      [TB, TB]            [task18, nt6]     [name_t18, n_t5]
3  job5   nj5     None      [TA, TA]           [task3, task7]       [name_t33, n7]
4  job6   nj6     None  [TA, TA, TA]  [task19, task6, task88]  [name_t19, n6, n88]
```

grouped by a `job` with listed its tasks, where tasks are defined by `task_type` between START and END

What I came up with so far:

handling None:
`df[['job', 'name', 'schedule']] = df[['job', 'name', 'schedule']].fillna(method='ffill')`

filtering rows for desired task types:
`df[df['task_type'].isin(['TA', 'TB'])]`

grouping the data:
`df.groupby(['job', 'name', 'schedule']).apply(lambda x: [list(x['task_type']), list(x['task']), list(x['task_name'])]).apply(pd.Series).reset_index(names=['job', 'name', 'schedule'])`

But the results is not what expect:

```
    job  name schedule             0                        1                    2
0  job1  n_j1       01          [TA]                 [task12]           [name_t12]
1  job3  n_j3       06          [TB]                 [task31]           [name_t31]
2  job4  n_j4       09      [TB, TB]            [task18, nt6]     [name_t18, n_t5]
3  job5   nj5       09      [TA, TA]           [task3, task7]       [name_t33, n7]
4  job6   nj6       09  [TA, TA, TA]  [task19, task6, task88]  [name_t19, n6, n88]
```

My question is how to get rid of `schedule` values for `job5`, `job6` and name the lists more friendly.
There should by more elegant way of doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a question. Why you want store lists as pandas values? I am not sure that pandas is meant for using it this way. Is there a particular reason why you want this?

Comment: @Aidis This is just a preparation for further code, which has certain objects structure. With such data creating the objects and relations is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Do the following steps on your initial `df`:

```
df[['job', 'name']] = df[['job', 'name']].fillna(method='ffill')

df = df.groupby(['job', 'name']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).applymap(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in [None, 'START', 'END']])

# replace empty lists with None on schedule column
df['schedule'] = df['schedule'].apply(lambda x: None if x == [] else x)
```

Comment: Thank you, but there are still filled ```schedule``` values for ```job5``` and ```job6```

Comment: @Mark the edit I just made will solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby(df["job"].ffill()).agg(
    lambda x: [v for v in x if v and v not in {"START", "END"}]
)
x["job"] = x["job"].str[0]
x["name"] = x["name"].str[0]
x["schedule"] = x["schedule"].str[0]

print(x.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Prints:

```
    job  name schedule     task_type                     task            task_name
0  job1  n_j1       01          [TA]                 [task12]           [name_t12]
1  job3  n_j3       06          [TB]                 [task31]           [name_t31]
2  job4  n_j4       09      [TB, TB]            [task18, nt6]     [name_t18, n_t5]
3  job5   nj5      NaN      [TA, TA]           [task3, task7]       [name_t33, n7]
4  job6   nj6      NaN  [TA, TA, TA]  [task19, task6, task88]  [name_t19, n6, n88]
```